# How I can update my container image in bluemix, without stop my actual service that use this container?

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

How I can update my container image in bluemix, without stop my actual service that use this container?

Normally I stop > removing > recreate a new container. That's is not very productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Bluemix Container Service now combines Docker and Kubernetes. Kubernetes is an open source project for managing infrastructure that you can deploy to Bluemix. Zero-downtime deployment is a native feature of Kubernetes.

You should consider migrating your old containers to the new IBM Container Service.

For more information on creating clusters:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html#clusters

Managing rolling deployments with IBM Bluemix Container Service
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_apps.html#cs_apps_rolling

Comment: Ok, I need to migrate my actual service? I created in docker because I needed a connection with oracle and my application, and a unique solution that worked on blue mix after a month of work, was using docker.

That's my first time in working with docker. Now I understand that I have a container, it's a part of SO where I run my application.

I installed others things for support, that is compatible with our service (that I made after run my container in blumix, using ssh).

I need to refresh my code without a stop in my container.